# boost asio transfer_exactly reads 0 bytes

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, boost, boost-asio

Given a sample server which transfers file contents over tcp -

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::system;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::vector;
using std::ios;
using stream_iter = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;

int main()
{
    ifstream input("movie.ogv", ios::in | ios::binary);
    vector<uint8_t> stream((stream_iter(input)), stream_iter());

    io_service ioservice;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioservice, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8000));
    tcp::socket socket(ioservice);
    acceptor.accept(socket);

    error_code ec;
    write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(stream), ec);
    if (ec) {
        cerr << ec.message() << endl;
    }
}
```

I wrote following client to extract starting header of file being transferred -

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace boost::system;
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::vector;
using std::ios;
using stream_iter = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;

int main()
{
    int header_size_ = 30000;
    error_code ec;
    vector<char> headerBytesBuf;
    headerBytesBuf.reserve(header_size_);
    io_service ioservice;
    tcp::socket socket(ioservice);
    socket.connect(tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8000));
    const auto bTransfer = read(socket, buffer(headerBytesBuf),
                                transfer_exactly(header_size_), ec);

    if (ec) {
        socket.close();
        std::cerr << ec.message();
    }

    std::cout << headerBytesBuf.size();
}
```

The relevant code is - `const auto bTransfer = read(socket, buffer(headerBytesBuf), transfer_exactly(header_size_), ec);` which reads 0 bytes into the vector while no error is recorded :/

Upon changing that line to -

```
std::array<char, 128> buf;
size_t total_transfer = 0;

while(total_transfer < header_size_) {
    size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf));
    total_transfer += len;
    if (len <= 0) break;
}
```

The `total_transfer` reports `30800` which I can now trim and append to my `vector` within the loop. But why isn't the first method working here?

Comment: Not 100% sure but i think you want to change `headerBytesBuf.reserve(header_size_);` to  `headerBytesBuf.resize(header_size_);`, as ASIO buffers work on raw data after initialization, they have no way to resize the vector. You are effectively passing a 0-sized buffer, which triggers the `The supplied buffers are full.` condition immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `boost::asio::read()`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload3.html

> The call will block until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - The completion_condition function object returns 0.

You are hitting the first condition because you are passing a 0-sized buffer.

All you need to do is change the

```
headerBytesBuf.reserve(header_size_);
```

to a

```
headerBytesBuf.resize(header_size_);
```

to fix the issue.